# Open Refine regex for alphabets

Tags: regex, data-cleaning, openrefine

i want to edit only alphabetic charcter from my cell 
.
what i have done

```
value.match(/.*?(\^[a-zA-Z]*$).*?/)
```

but it returns null

i am try to clean address column in my data set following are the sample address

H3656 GALI#4 BLOCK-D,  AREA 1

H#36/17 SECTOR 5D **AREA 2**

**AREA 3** BLOCK-B NORTH NAZIMABAD

GERMANY AL JANNAT BENQUET SECTOR 16 **Area 2 with short name**

so that i first try to remove all numbers from my string

Comment: Hello. Could you post an example of your data and of what you wan to get? It would then be easier to provide a specific answer.

Comment: @EttoreRizza question has been eddited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the numbers, the most direct approach is probably:

```
value.replace(/\d+/, "")
```

[image]

If for any reason you want to find only the alphabetic characters, as indicated by the title of your question, this will be more effective than a value.match() :

```
value.find(/\p{L}\s?/).join("")
```

(\p{L} is a [Java regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - Openrefine is written in Java - equivalent to [a-zA-Z], but which also takes into account Unicode characters like accented letters.)

In general, you should [avoid using the .match() method](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1296) unless you know exactly what you are doing. In 90% of cases, it is actually `.find()` that is desired.

Comment: can you also please guide about solution of my problem.
as you know its data cleaning problem.
am i on right direction b/c my ultimate problem is finding a area

Comment: I did'nt understand that your problem is finding an area. Your questions are about alphabet and numbers, the word "area" is not mentioned at all. What's exactly what you want to find in those strings? Do you want to get the parts in bold?

Comment: yes exactly 
i want that part which is bold
area means location (that is address of person) i just want to grab location/vicinity/arear of a person 
and make analysis on that person

Comment: Could you edit/elaborate your question and provide a real example? Based on your examples, looks like you want the word AREA followed by a number, or the Word area followed by a number and the rest of the string, or you don't want the word area at all if it's followed by 1. it's really unclear.